# Parallelize with SGE_TASK_ID

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a block of code that works as I want it to but is really inefficient.

```
for f in *.GeneSet; do
#Figure out the cell type by removing "Genes.GeneSet" from the end of the filename
  cell_type=${f%.GeneSet}

  # Process the file
  for i in `seq 1 22`; do
    python make_annot.py \
    --gene-set-file "$f" \
    --gene-coord-file  ENSG_coord.txt \
    --bimfile 1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.EUR.QC.${i}.bim \
    --annot-file ${cell_type}.${i}.annot.gz
    done
done
```

This works well. Except that because its a nested for-loop and very inefficient. I would like to use `$SGE_TASK_ID` to run each iteration independently. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't see "SGE_TASK_ID" in the existing code...?

Comment: yes, thats because I haven't implemented it. I am wondering how it can be used to make my code more efficient. Did I write the question incorrectly?

Comment: Googling that name comes up with references to Sun GridEngine; are you trying to use *that* to run your code?

Comment: Mhat values may `$SGE_TASK_ID` have? If they are between 1 and 22, then you could simply use that instead of `$i` in your `for` loop.  Also, aren't you caring about the X, Y and MT chromosomes?